# Which tools works for patents analytics?

Tags: patentability, design-patent, patenting-an-algorithm, text-analysis, analytics

I'm looking for getting some insights though patents analytics to know if my company's products are patentable. I already check some papers about it. I'm just starting so it would be cool to get an expert's point of view. Thanks

Comment: Can you explain more about what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: If you are talking about current products that are on the market, than almost for sure not patentable. Products in development might be patentable, but someone would have to know all about the product. You can’t publicly disclose before patenting so I’m not sure we can help.

Comment: As for patent search sites, I’m partial to https://www.lens.org/

Comment: Professional point of view: if you're developing them and they are not purely software, they are very probably patentable to some extent. With software it gets more complicated and depends on the case, but changes are still good.

Comment: The lens has some analytics. You can see who the prolific inventors and assignees are within search results, for example.

Comment: You should get someone with experience with patenting involved - there is the issue of identifying IP, select what to patent and what to keep as trade secrets, writing specifications, drawings, claims... May be try to file a provisional immediately and than you have a year to drag your feet and make decisions. You should also consider in which countries you want to file...

Comment: What do you mean by tools and by patent analytics?

Comment: changed a non-answer answer to a comment.

Comment: This link might be of value: https://www.wipo.int/publications/en/details.jsp?id=4168

Answer (score 2):

One resource I've found is the [WIPO Manual on Open Source Patent Analytics](https://wipo-analytics.github.io). From its introduction:

> This book provides a practical guide to free and open source software
> tools for patent analytics. The aim of the WIPO Manual on Open Source
> Patent Analytics is to provide a practical introduction to patent
> analytics without assuming prior knowledge of patents or programming
> languages.

The USPTO has a [useful page](https://developer.uspto.gov/open-analytics) also. Of the free patent search sites, I recommend [The Lens](https://www.lens.org). There is a "Analytics" tab which generates an array of graphical analyses on the search results. The Lens is free. If you create an account you obtain some useful features like saved searches, but can be used without an account. There are a lot of nice features that Google Patents doesn't have.